# How to only change child components while parent component dont re render upon route change?

Tags: reactjs

So, while changing the route using `react-router-dom` I have to again add i.e re-render my header and sidebar component in that route. Which effect my page load time.

Following is my code for better understanding

`index.js`

```
 ...
<Route exact path="/" component={UI} />
<Route exact path="/rms" component={rms} />
 ...
```

`UI.js`

```
<div>
    <Header />
    <div className="mainbody">
      <Sidebar history={this.props.history}/>
      <div className="main">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`rms.js`

```
<div>
    <Header />
    <div className="mainbody">
      <Sidebar history={this.props.history} />
      <div className="main">
        ... //new content
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

P.S I m still a newb to react, so do point out if I am doing it wrong or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil
>
> -Donald Knuth

You said that re-rendering your header and sidebar are affecting your page load time.  I find that suspect.  A single extra component, unless it's doing something ***crazy***, should not meaningfully impact your load time.

I'd double check how you're metricing things, but before you even start metricing things you should make sure page load is actually a problem.  If it's not more than a few seconds, you likely are better off focusing your efforts elsewhere.

Comment: But, what I am asking is it even possible or it is what it is?